# Confusion about Mallows' Cp

Tags: regression, model-selection

I am trying to use Mallows' $C_p$ to select linear regression models. I have been reading the excellent text by Cosma Shalizi at [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/TALR/TALR.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/TALR/TALR.pdf)
(page 323 to 327).

That text already gives 2 separate definitions of $C_p$. The first definition, which is convincingly derived from first principles is as follows:

[image: eq.1]

The second definition, definitely not the author's choice, is:

[image: eq.2]

From the source code, this seems to be the definition used by the ols_mallows_cp function in R. The Shalizi text states that eq.2 should be close to $p$ for the right model, not close to $0$ like eq.1.

Wikipedia, on the other hand, gives equations which differ from the previous ones by constants:

[image: ![eq.3]

and

[image: eq. 4]

Wikipedia states that $C_p$ should be approaching $p$ for a good model.

Of course I can see that the constants will not make any differences if the sole purpose is to rank different models. However, I am puzzled by the co-existence of multiple not equivalent formulae. If the $C_p$ is the expected out-of-sample MSE, I would surmise that only eq, 1 would be correct. I would be interested to learn how the other definitions arise.

At a more practical level, I cannot reconcile that $C_p$ should be approaching $p$ if eq. 2 is used and also if eq.4 (which adds 2 to the result of eq. 2) is used. So I would be happy to receive any guidance on that as well.

A last question is whether it is correct that $\hat\sigma^{2}$ is best estimated by the MSE of the residuals in the model at hand.

Comment: Beware: You must pay attention to the exact definition of $p$ in each case; some sources included the constant in $p$ while others exclude it (and then add 1 to $p$ to account for it). This applies to all manner of formulas, not just $C_p$.

Comment: Thank you. But in both texts (Shalizi's and Wikipedia) $p$ is the number of predictors. Moreover, the differences between eq.1 and 3 and between eq. 2 and 4 go in opposite directions, so that a different definition of $p$ could not be an explanation in both cases.

Comment: Yes, it couldn't explain all of it; I just raised it as a potential explanation of the difference either between 1 and 3 or between 2 and 4. I'd delete the comment but your response is so useful I'd worry about losing the context for it.